# Android actionbar customize menuitem background

Tags: android, xamarin, android-actionbar, xamarin.android, customization

I have a menu in my android activity (I am working with Xamarin.Android) and that contains several items, like this one:

```
<item android:id="@+id/menuitem1"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share"
       android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

I can customize the whole ActionBar. But I want to customize just one item in the actionbar. Like the following Icon in the middle (the blue one):

[image: Sample Picture]

How can I achive this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try custom action bar..

Answer (score 0):

First thing that we need to do is set up the basic colour values in res/values/colors.xml that we used in Jeff’s Generator tool:

```
<color name="sa_green">#14a804</color>
<color name="stacked_green">#118504</color>
<color name="accent_green">#97e08f</color>
```

create a new style, which we’ll call “ActionBar” in res/values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/sa_green</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@color/stacked_green</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@color/sa_green</item>
</style>
```

Now it must set this style on the ActionBar by adding an actionBarStyle to the theme in res/values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>
.
.
.
```

try this ...